# Django will not recognize a settings module

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a settings module for a Django app per [this guide](https://www.rdegges.com/2011/the-perfect-django-settings-file/).

I have the settings module created, which contains the **__init__**.py, common.py, and dev.py. However, when I attempt `python manage.py runserver --settings=settings.dev`, I get the import error:

*"No module named 'settings"*

If I attempt `python manage.py runserver --settings={APP_NAME}.settings.dev`, I get the import error:

*"No module named 'common'*

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but can't seem to figure it out. Here are the contents of my files:

**dev.py:**

```
from common import *
# from os.path import join, normpath


# DEBUG CONFIG
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
# END DEBUG CONFIG


# DATABASE CONFIG
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'Local instance wampmysqld64',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',

    }
}
# END DATABASE CONFIG
```

**common.py**
    import os

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'test',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'API_PG.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PG.wsgi.application'





# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-          validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME':'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
    'NAME':'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
     },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**manage.py:**

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PG.settings.dev")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
       raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

root_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.split(__file__)[0])
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(root_path, 'PG.settings.dev'))
sys.path.insert(0, root_path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PG.settings.dev")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

PG is the name of the project; I've tried removing it and using just 'settings.dev' in both manage.py and wsgi.py, but with no luck.

There is a similar thread here, but the issue seems to be different.

**folder structure:** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ3e5.png)

Comment: show us your folder structure

Comment: try to replace `from common import *` to `from .common import *`. And share `__init__.py`

Comment: Rustem is most likely right, also, you posted your secret key online. While not much of a deal since at this time it is hopefully not critical, it's a good habit to remove sensitive information from what you post (same goes for your database settings which show both username and password, although we could have guessed those :P)

Comment: @Rustem `from .common import *` becomes an unused import statement, and the `__init__.py` is blank

Comment: @sebb I edited the post with the structure at the bottom, thank you

Comment: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PG.settings.dev") try to change this from PG.settings.dev to settings.dev

same in wsg, also remove sys.path.instert, its not needed

Comment: Use PyCharm(If you don't yet) to mitigate these kind of issues, PyCharm can resolve the references even inside strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use a different settings module for your project what I suggest you try to do is to add the "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" in your wsgi.py file. I was having issues with this before and after doing it like this it was working properly. I hope this solves your issue.

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/project)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'your_settings_module'
```

Comment: I use Pycharm, and had to go to the Edit Configurations menu to specify the settings module. For anyone looking on, this answer should still work regardless.